# django internationalization doesn't work

Tags: django, internationalization

I have created translation strings in the template and in the application view.

Then I ran:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l it
```

and the file it/LC_MESSAGES/django.po has been created

I have now translated strings in the django.po file, and then I ran:

```
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

And I receive:

```
processing file django.po in /home/jobber/Desktop/library/books/locale/it/LC_MESSAGES
```

My settings.py looks like this:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'it'
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = ( "django.core.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media", )
USE_I18N = True
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = ( 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)
```

but I still always see English text. Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe your browser language is English. The LocaleMiddleware tries to detect the language based on [this algorithm](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/deployment/#how-django-discovers-language-preference) (i.e. Accept-Language  HTTP header).
So you can either remove the LocaleMiddleware to avoid this or use the [set_language  redirect view](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/i18n/internationalization/#the-set-language-redirect-view).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the accepted answer: If you're using Firefox you can install [Quick Locale Switcher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1333/) to test your application with different languages (based on the browser language). It adds a button at the bottom of your screen where you can easily change your browser language.